# LMM for data with a quadratic relationship, and continuous fixed factor?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, continuous-data

Apologies in advance if I've missed an answer here, but I have two problems that, compounding, seem to be tripping me up. I have a series of measurements taken at different times of day that appear to have a quadratic relationship (plot below). I'm trying to use a LMM (lmer), but I'm having trouble reconciling how to simultaneously deal with time of day on the 24-hr clock as a continuous fixed factor and using time as a quadratic term, as I've only analyzed basic linear models with categorical fixed factors. For simplicity, say my model, were this a basic linear model, would be Meters ~ Time. I would then be looking for something like Meters ~ Time^2 + Time? At this point, I've confused myself so thoroughly that I'm not quite sure how to word my question.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem stemmed from my Time of Day formatting. R can be converted into a continuous format using POSIXct, e.g.:

```
data$Time=as.POSIXct(data$Time,format="%H:%M",tz="Australia/Perth")
```

From there, code for a quadratic formula as suggested elsewhere, in this case, e.g.:

```
lm(Meters ~ poly(Time,2) + SD, data = data)
```